# Pass a class member function as a function parameter

Tags: c++, syntax

**I have 2 C++ Class questions:**

The 1st question is: How can I make it so I can pass a class member function as a parameter in another function & how can I then run/call that function? And how can I do the same with a class static function. It maybe easier to understand my question by looking at this code:

```
class DebuggingManager
{
    string testLog;

    bool test1()
    {
         // run test & return whether it passed or failed
    }    

    static bool test2()
    {

    }

    // How can I call a member function?
    void catalogueTest( string testName, bool DebuggingManager::*nMemberFunction )
    {
        testLog += "Status of " + testName + ": " + ((*)nMemberFunction()) + "\n"; 
    }

    // How can I call a static function?
    void catalogueTest( string testName, bool DebuggingManager::*nStaticFunction )
    {
        testLog += "Status of " + testName + ": " + DebuggingManager::nStaticFunction() + "\n"; 
    }

    // how do I pass a member function or a static function as a parameter in another function 
    bool runTests()
    {
         catalogueTest( "Test of member functin", test1() );
         catalogueTest( "Test of static functin", test2() );
    }

};
```

The 2nd question is: Is it bad(or dangerous) practice to call a class member (or static) function indirectly like the above. I have a feeling this is really bad C++ practice?

**EDIT: Implementing advice**
Thanks for the reply, I have attempted to implement that advice, its alot to get my head around though, would this be correct?

```
    // I have a feeling that ParameterList is incorect, would I pass the implicit obj as a parameter or is it done automatically like in normal object function calls?
    typedef bool (DebuggingManager::*MemberPointerType)(ParameterList); 

    void catalogueTest( tstring testName, DebuggingManager* obj, MemberPointerType *nMemberFunction )
    {
        debugLog += _T("Status of ") + testName + _T(": ") + (obj->*nMemberFunction)() + _T("\r\n");
    }

    void catalogueStaticTest( tstring testName, bool DebuggingManager::nStaticFunction )
    {
        debugLog += _T("Status of ") + testName + _T(": ") + nStaticFunction + _T("\r\n");
    }
```

Comment: I'm surprised this isn't answered already. Maybe everyone else is tired too and doesn't want to look up the syntax for member function pointers for the 500th time.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463112/pointer-to-a-c-class-member-function-as-a-global-functions-parameter which gives a link to http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html which has the syntax and things to watch out for when declaring/using normal and static member function pointers. As for whether it's bad I would say: probably not in a particular case (like testing, or perhaps others), but it wouldn't be good to do as a day-to-day practice for writing code, since it is tricky, and since there are better mechanisms for most anything you would use them for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662891/how-can-i-pass-a-member-function-where-a-free-function-is-expected

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Static member functions of classes are ultimately no different than regular functions. They're really just syntactic sugar; the function is simply has a name that include `Classname::`.

Non-static members are another matter altogether. There are two important things to remember about non-static member functions (NSMF).

First, every non-static member function has access to the non-static members of the class that they are a member of. This is possible even though you can have two objects of the same class that happen to store different data. If you have two `std::string` objects, they each store different strings. Executing a `find` on one string can return a found result in one but not the other.

This is because every NSMF has an implicit `this` pointer. `this` refers to, not merely a class, but the actual *object* upon which that NSMF operates. When you do this:

```
std::string aString("data");
aString.find("da");
```

The `find` function takes a string argument, but it also gets `aString` as its `this`. Every time `find` looks for the members of its class, it will be looking at `aString`'s data.

So let's look at your prospective call of an NSMF:

```
((*)nMemberFunction())
```

Where is the object that it gets its `this` pointer from? Without an object, the NSMF could not access the non-static members of the object, since there is no object for it to find them in. This is not legal.

So, rule #1 about NSMFs: You **must** call them with an actual instance of the class that the NSMF is a member of (or a derived class thereof). You cannot just take an NSMF pointer and call it like a function pointer; you have to call it on a live object of that type.

Rule #2: the syntax for NSMF pointers is really ugly.

To define a variable (or argument) named `arg` of NSMF pointer type, you do this:

```
ReturnType (ClassName::*arg)(ParameterList);
```

Where `ReturnType` is the return type of the function, `ParameterList` is the list of arguments taken by the function, and `ClassName` is the name of the class to which the NSMF pointer belongs.

Given the ugliness, it is usually best to wrap it in a typedef:

```
typedef ReturnType (ClassName::*MemberPointerType)(ParameterList);
```

Thus creating the typedef `MemberPointerType`, which is a NSMF pointer.

Given an object named `object`, which is of type `ClassName`, you would call the member pointer `arg` as follows:

```
ReturnType value = (object.*arg)(Params);
```

Where `Params` are the arguments you wish to pass. If `object` is a pointer to a `ClassName` instead of a reference or a value, then you use `object->*arg` instead.

One more thing: you **must** use `&` to get the member pointer name. Unlike function pointers, NSMF pointers do not automatically convert to member pointers. You have to ask for them directly. So if `ClassName` has a member called Function that fit the above `ReturnType` and `ParameterList`, you would fill `arg` as follows:

```
arg = &ClassName::Function;
```

Rule #3: non-static member pointers are **not pointers**. Yes, they can be set to NULL (technically, they can be set to 0), but they are *not* the same thing as a pointer.

Most real C and C++ compilers will allow you to cast a function pointer to a `void*` and back. The standards consider this undefined behavior, but it's not-entirely-unknown to do this. You absolutely *cannot* do this with a NSMF pointer, on virtually all C++ compilers. Indeed, the `sizeof(MemberPointerType)` will likely not be the same size as `void*`.

So, NSMF pointers are not regular pointers. Do not treat them as such.

Comment: Wouldn't you have to say `(object.*arg)(Params);` because of operator precedence?

Comment: @Kerrek SB: Yes, `.*` has lower precedence than a function call.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: Thanks for your reply. I have attempted to implement what you said, is it correct?

Answer (score 3):

In C++ 11 they came up with a way to do that. Read about [function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [bind](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) operations.

In your case, let's say you wanted to call functions of type test1. (i.e. of form bool FunctionName().

```
void catalogueTest( string testName, std::function<bool()> myFunction)
{
    testLog += "Status of " + testName + ": " + myFunction() + "\n"; 
}
```

And call it like this:

```
DebuggingManager myInstance
myInstance->catalogueTest("TestName", std::bind(&DebuggingManager::test1, myInstance));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you want, where X is your class, T is the return of your method and Args are the arguments your function receives.

If your method takes no args, just don't pass them as in test1 and test2.

If your method has void return, than erase the T template and write void where T was on the methods signature.

If you have link errors, remember to define doMember and doStatic in your .h file. By define I mean write the entire function, not just its signature. That's due to template issues.

```
#include <string>

class DebuggingManager
{

private:

    std::string testLog;

    bool test1()
    {
        // run test & return whether it passed or failed
        return true;
    }

    static bool test2()
    {
        return false;
    }

    int test3(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }

    static int test4(int a, int b)
    {
        return a - b;
    }

    void catalogueTest(std::string testName, int result)
    {
        testLog += "Status of " + testName + ": " + std::to_string(result) + "\n";
    }

    // How can I call a member function?
    template <typename X, typename T, typename ...Args>
    T doMember(X* obj, T(X::* func)(Args...), Args... args)
    {
        return (obj->*func)(args...);
    }

    // How can I call a static function?
    template <typename T, typename ...Args>
    T doStatic(T func(Args...), Args... args)
    {
        return func(args...);
    }

public:

    // how do I pass a member function or a static function as a parameter in another function 
    void runTests()
    {
        catalogueTest("Test of member functin", doMember(this, &DebuggingManager::test1));
        catalogueTest("Test of member functin", doMember(this, &DebuggingManager::test3, 10, 20));
        catalogueTest("Test of static functin", doStatic(DebuggingManager::test2));
        catalogueTest("Test of static functin", doStatic(DebuggingManager::test4, 10, 20));
        std::cout << testLog << std::endl;
    }

};
```