# Pass Member Function Pointers to parent class

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, pointer-to-member

I'm working on a Pacman game in C++, but have run into a problem with member function pointers. I have 2 classes, `pacman` and `ghost`, that both inherit from `Mouvement`. In the subclasses, I need to pass a function to a function in `Mouvement`. However, I can't simply have static functions as then I would need static variables, which would not work.

I have tried passing `&this->movingUp` which throws the error 'Cannot create a non-constant pointer to member function'

I have tried passing `&<ghost or pacman>::movingUp` which throws the error "Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'void (*)(int)' with an rvalue of type 'void (::*)(int)' "

Here's what's relevent: (I cut out most of it, so that you only see what's necessary for this problem)

```
class cMouvement {
protected:

    int curDirection = -3; // Variables that are used in the 'movingUp, etc' functions.
    int newDirection = -3; // And therefore can't be static


public:

void checkIntersection(void (*function)(int), bool shouldDebug){

    // Whole bunch of 'If's that call the passed function with different arguments

}
```

And then class `pacman` and `ghost`, which are very similar at this point.

```
class pacman : public cMouvement {

    void movingUp(int type){
        // Blah blah blah
    }

    // movingDown, movingLeft, movingRight... (Removed for the reader's sake)



public:
    /*Constructor function*/

    void move(bool shouldDebug){
        if (curDirection == 0)     {checkIntersection(&movingUp, false);}
        else if (curDirection == 1)     {checkIntersection(&movingRight, false);}
        else if (curDirection == 2)     {checkIntersection(&movingDown, false);}
        else if (curDirection == 3)     {checkIntersection(&movingLeft, false);}
    }

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you create a virtual function in `cMouvement` and let `checkIntersection` to call that virtual function

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to supply the signature of a member function, instead of a regular function.

```
void checkIntersection(void (ghost::*)(int), bool shouldDebug){
```

See [Passing a member function as an argument in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662891/c-passing-member-function-as-argument)

If you really need to supply functions from `ghost` **and** `pacman` you need to rethink your strategy. Maybe use virtual functions instead.

Comment: Yup, I used virtual functions as per John Smith's suggestion. Thanks though!