# How can I avoid this code duplication?

Tags: c++, refactoring, stdbind

I have two methods which have almost the same code except for two methods they call (and some other details I can easily parameterize). However, those method calls have the same signature, so I think I can generalize them into a single method.

```
class A{
    IApi* m_pApi;
    void M1();
    void M2();
public:
    void DoThings();
}

void A::M1(){
    int i;
    bool b;    
    m_pApi->method1( &i, &b );    
    //Other stuff...
}

void A::M2(){
    int i;
    bool b;    
    m_pApi->method2( &i, &b );
    //Other stuff...
}

void A::DoThings(){
    M1();
    M2();
}
```

I can figure out how to "parameterize" the "Other stuff" code, but the problem are the calls to `method1` and `method2`. I think I have to use `std::bind` somehow, but I can't do something like this...

```
void A::M( std::function<void(int*,bool*)> f ){
    int i;
    bool b;
    f( &i, &b );
}

void A::DoThings(){
    M( std::bind( ???, m_pApi ) ); //M1
    M( std::bind( ???, m_pApi ) ); //M2
}
```

The problem here is that `m_pApi` is not a concrete class (it's an interface implemented by a bunch of concrete classes), so I'm not sure if I can do the usual `&Class::Method` thing. Suggestions?

Comment: Could you not just use an if statement and a boolean parameter flag?

Comment: Actually it's four methods (M1 ... M4). I could use an enum but I'm sure there's a more elegant solution.

Comment: Are you trying to just try a facade over the m_pApi class? This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662891/c-passing-member-function-as-argument

Comment: I also thought of using pointers to member functions, but I never used them when dealing with an inheritance hierarchy. If I use a `void (IApi::*)(int*, bool*)`, would it bind correctly when I combine it with `m_pApi` to perform the call? I'll go make a quick test at ideone.

Comment: @dario Yes, they work as they should (pointer to member of base can be applied to a derived instance).

Comment: are you sure bind won't work? even if interface is not a concrete class, you are not really instantiating the object by binding stuff ... just a guess

Comment: @Zeks: I think pointers to members fit this scenario better, since they are less generic and thus give more information to those who read the code, and better type safety as well. In other words, laziness > curiosity  :P

Comment: sorry, wrong test case http://codepad.org/Oj08FpUS this compiles in qt and outputs "1 called" and "2 called"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [pointers to member function](http://mdzahidh.wordpress.com/2008/07/16/pointer-to-c-class-methods-or-should-you-call-em-method-pointers/).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct IApi {
    void method1(int * i, bool * b) {
        *i = 1; *b = true;
    }
    void method2(int * i, bool * b) {
        *i = 2; *b = false;
    }
};

class A {
    IApi* m_pApi;
    void M(void (IApi::*)(int*, bool*));
public:
    A() : m_pApi(new IApi()) {}
    void DoThings();
};

void A::M(void (IApi::*mptr)(int*, bool*)) {
    int i;
    bool b;    
    (m_pApi->*mptr)( &i, &b );    
    cout << i << ' ' << b << endl;
}

void A::DoThings(){
    M(&IApi::method1);
    M(&IApi::method2);
}

int main() {
    A a;
    a.DoThings();
}
```

Comment: +1: You beat me to it, I was doing the  exact same thing at ideone :P