# assign `this` to `MyClass *instance`, `instance->member` is not referencing same memory as `this->member`

Tags: c++

In my cpp implementation I have:

```
static MyClass *instance;
```

floating freely outside all containing scopes (curly {}). I've tried initializing it to nullptr too.

```
void MyClass::myMethod() {
 instance = this;
 LOG("Hello, %d, %d", wList, instance->wList);
```

The above log displays an arbitrary location for member object pointer `wList` but `instance` should be pointing to the same data that `this` does, and hence the same `wList`, but it doesn't. `instance->wList` is still 0. What's happening here?

Comment: Who knows? Present a testcase so we can tell you.

Comment: You can't use `%d` to print a pointer reliably - use `%p`.

Comment: I've rolled this back to the original question @LightnessRacesinOrbit those extra tags proved to be spot on for locating the problem. Obviously the solution isn't ideal but as a quick n dirty hack I don't think anyone had predicted what the real cause of error was.. Saves passing member function pointers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662891/c-passing-member-function-as-argument

Comment: I take it back! I found I had redeclared `wList` at the start of the method! Must stop work when my eyes close :)

Comment: No, those tags are utterly useless and shall not be used, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Mark Ransom noted in the comments, you can't use the `%d` format specifier to print a pointer, you must use `%p` in order for your code to be portable.  It's technically Undefined Behavior to use anything besides `%p` for pointers, but in all likelihood you'll see that it will seem to work ok on 32-bit systems.

However, on 64-bit systems, which I'd wager you're using, it blows up.  Pointers are 8 bytes, but `printf` only tries to read 4 bytes off of the stack when it sees `%d`.  For the second `%d` specifier, it reads the next 4 bytes, which are the other 4 bytes of the pointer—if you're seeing 0 for that, it probably means that your pointer was allocated within the first 4 GB of memory on a little-endian system (i.e. its value was something like `0x00000000'xxxxxxxx`).  The 8 bytes on the stack from the second pointer passed to `printf` never get read.

The `%p` specifier portably prints a pointer on all platforms, regardless of whether they're 32 bits, 64 bits, or some other size.  One unfortunate consequence of this is that the exact output format is *implementation-defined*, meaning it can and does change between systems.  Some systems might use a leading `0x` or `0X`, while others might have no prefix at all and just print the raw hex value.  Some might pad to the left with 0's, and others might not.

If you want to control the exact output, then you can use a format of your choice (e.g. `%08x` or `%016llx`) *as long as you cast the pointer appropriately for that specifier*.  For example, here's how you would do that on 32- and 64-bit systems:

```
printf("0x%08x\n", (unsigned int)(uintptr_t)myPointer);           // 32-bit
printf("0x%016llx\n", (unsigned long long)(uintptr_t)myPointer);  // 64-bit
```

The reason for casting twice is to avoid spurious compiler warnings, since some compilers will complain if you cast from a pointer type to an integer type which isn't guaranteed to be large enough to hold a pointer.

Comment: thanks for the comprehensive answer with reinforcement from Mark Ransom. I will be able to try again tonight but I had completely overlooked 64bit pointers as was running through the Android emulator.

Comment: Yep well argued, my error was in fact that I redeclared `wList` at line one of the calling function. Your at least 100x as right as me so well done.