# How to properly pass member function as argument in this situation in C++?

Tags: c++, functional-programming, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

I want to pass a member function of my C++ class to another member function of the same class. I did some research and found these similar questions on SO.

[Passing a member function as an argument in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662891/c-passing-member-function-as-argument)

[Function pointer to member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402579/c-function-pointer-to-member-function)

They don't cover my specific case in an identical manner, but I wrote my code and would think that I adjusted the right parts to make it work in my situation. However, the compiler seems to disagree with me on that...

I have the following setup in my C++ class:

**CutDetector.h**

```
class CutDetector {
   double thresholdForFrameIndex(int frameIndex, vector<double> diffs, int steps, double (CutDetector::*thresholdFunction)(vector<double>diffs)); // should take other functions as args
   double calcMean(vector<double> diffs); // should be passed as argument
   double calcMeanMinMax(vector<double> diffs); // should be passed as argument
   double calcMedian(vector<double> diffs); // should be passed as argument
}
```

**CutDetector.h**

```
double thresholdForFrameIndex(int frameIndex, vector<double> diffs, int steps, double (CutDetector::*thresholdFunction)(vector<double>diffs)) {
    vector<double> window = ... init the window vector ;
    double threshold = thresholdFunction(window);
    return threshold;
}
```

However, passing the `thresholdFunction` as an argument like this doesn't work. The compiler complains with the following error:

> **error**: called object type `'double (CutDetector::*)(vector<double>)'`
>   is not a function or function pointer

Can anyone see why my setup doesn't work and suggest how I can make it so that it works? Basically what I want is to be able to pass any member function that calculates a *threshold* (i.e. `calcMean`, `calcMeanMinMax`, `calcMedian`) to the other member function `thresholdForFrameIndex`.

Comment: 1. Are those *both* really in CutDetector.h, and 2. Did you intentionally omit the `CutDetector::` qualifier on the second snippet definition (i.e. is that a free function and *not* the member declared in the prior class)?

Comment: You probably want to pass your vector<double> as a const & to avoid a costly copy operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To invoke a pointer to member function, you need to supply an object:

```
double threshold = (this->*thresholdFunction)(window);
                   ^^^^^^^^                 ^
```

Comment: thanks, that seems like the solution I am looking for! however, when using exactly this syntax the compiler complains again with  _error: invalid use of 'this' outside of a non-static member function_

Comment: @nburk well that sort-of answers my second question up in general-comment. You need an instance. Still don't know if that omission of `CutDetector::` was intentional or not. Do you see you defined that function as `double thresholdForFrameIndex(...)` rather than `double CutDetector::thresholdForFrameIndex(...)` ?

Comment: ah, you're totally right! this was actually my fault, in my `.cpp`-file I didnt declare the function as being a member of my class... now it works! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't call a member function without an instance of the class. You need to do something like this:

```
CutDetector cd;
double threshold = (cd.*thresholdFunction)(window);
```

Or if you have a `CutDetector` pointer somewhere:

```
double threshold = (pcd->*thresholdFunction)(window);
```

Or if `thresholdForFrameIndex` is a member function:

```
double threshold = (this->*thresholdFunction)(window);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be easier for you here to make `calcMean`, `calcMeanMinMax` and `calcMedian` **static** functions and treat like all others non-member functions. Others answers are correct, but in your case i guess that would be better for class design.