# MultiThread program in VC++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am trying to do a threaded application to infinitely print a set of numbers after enqueing them. I get this error:

Error   1   error C3867: 'Test::ThreadFunc': function call missing argument list; use '&Test::ThreadFunc' to create a pointer to member.

What am I doing wrong? What is the mistake ?

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <chrono>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <list>

class Test {
    std::list<int> queue;
    std::mutex m;

public:
    void ThreadFunc()
    {
        // Loop is required, otherwise thread will exit
        for (;;)
        {
            bool read = false;
            int value;
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);

                if (queue.size())
                {
                    value = queue.front();
                    read = true;
                    queue.pop_back();
                }
            }

            if (read)
            {
                // send(header.data(), header.dataSize());
                // send(proto.data(), proto.dataSize());
                printf("Hello %d\n", value);
            }

            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
        }
    }

    void TestFunc()
    {
        std::thread thread(ThreadFunc);
        thread.detach();

        int i = 0;
        // Loops only as a test example
        for (;;)
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(2000));
            queue.push_back(i++);
            // Queue Message(header, payload);
        }
    }

};

int main()
{
    Test test;
    test.TestFunc();
}
```

Comment: The error message explains the issue exactly and even tells you what to change in the code.

Comment: I changed the statement - std::thread thread(ThreadFunc) to std::thread thread(&Test::ThreadFunc);
It then gives me an error saying : 

Error 1 error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments

Comment: Right. You can only invoke `ThreadFunc` on an instance of the class it belongs to since it's a member function. What are you trying to do? Why is `ThreadFunc` a member of class `Test`? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Well, I am invoking it from a member function. wouldn't it pass the this pointer implicitly ?

Comment: I am trying to print infinite numbers. That's it. If I need to take ThreadFunc() out of the class, I can do that. Would that work ?
What's the reason that ThreadFunc cannot be a member function ?

Comment: No, it won't pass it implicitly. You can use `std::bind`.

Answer (score 1):

You're attempting to pass a pointer to a member function of a class. When you do this, there's an argument added to the function, tacitly, that is a pointer to the instance of the class that you're invoking the function on. In your case, the pointer to the class will be the `this` pointer.

See this for syntax reference: [Start thread with member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673585/start-thread-with-member-function)

To answer your comment, why isn't it passed implicitly? You're not calling the function as a member of a class, you're passing the member function by pointer. This is a different, unique, situation, see this reference: [Passing a member function as an argument in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662891/c-passing-member-function-as-argument)

Also, to save a little future headache, the next problem that comes up is that std::thread's constructor takes its arguments by value, so if you need to pass any arguments by reference, take a look at std::ref.

Comment: Thank you, That helped a lot ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the fix. This works. Thank you @mock_blatt

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <chrono>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <list>



class Test {
std::list<int> queue;
std::mutex m;

public:
    void ThreadFunc()
    {
        // Loop is required, otherwise thread will exit
        for (;;)
            {
                bool read = false;
                int value;
                {
                    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);

                    if (queue.size())
                    {
                        value = queue.front();
                        read = true;
                        queue.pop_back();
                    }
                }

        if (read)
        {
        // send(header.data(), header.dataSize());
        // send(proto.data(), proto.dataSize());
            printf("Hello %d\n", value);
        }

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
    }
}

 void TestFunc()
 {
    std::thread thread(std::bind(&Test::ThreadFunc, this));
    thread.detach();

    int i = 0;
    // Loops only as a test example
    for (;;)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(2000));
        queue.push_back(i++);
        // Queue Message(header, payload);
    }
}

};

int main()
{
 Test test;
test.TestFunc();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `std::thread thread(ThreadFunc);` to `std::thread thread(Test::ThreadFunc, this);`