# how to split function: bind

Tags: c++, posix, bind

I need to compile a `bind` function in a Posix embedded, and can't use `boost::bind` or `std::bind`.

So I want to split the function:
 `threadReducer.reduce(boost::bind(&DepthMap::observeDepthRow, this, _1, _2, _3), 3, height-3, 10);`

where the function observeDepthRow:
`void DepthMap::observeDepthRow(int yMin, int yMax, RunningStats* stats)`
and the function reduce:
`void IndexThread::reduce(boost::function<void(int,int,RunningStats*)> callPerIndex, int first, int end, int stepSize = 0)`

Plz, help me split the function, I am not good at C++

Comment: Why can't you use `boost::bind` (or `std::bind` for that matter)? Especially if you (apparently) can still continue to use `boost::function`?

Comment: this is my previous code, I need change all. The function reduce, is click "follow symbol", and show the function.

Comment: My posix embedded can't use the library 'boost'

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use boost or c++11 .. in that in that case you may try like this :

```
void IndexThread::reduce(void(*function)(int,int,RunningStats*), int first, int end, int stepSize = 0)
```

and make your `observeDepthRow static`

```
static void DepthMap::observeDepthRow(int yMin, int yMax, RunningStats* stats)
```

Then you can call it like this :

```
threadReducer.reduce(observeDepthRow, 3, height-3, 10);
```

although in this case you will have to make your method `static` if you do not wish so do have look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662891/c-passing-member-function-as-argument).