# C++ using passed function

Tags: c++, c++11

I have two functions one of them takes a function as an argument this works just fine, but I want to call this passed function in my second one.

```
class XY {   
 public:

   void first(void f());
   void second();        
 };

 void XY::first(void f()){

 }

 void XY::second(){
 f(); //passed function from first()
 }
```

Comment: Do you call second from first or do you call second independently at a later point?

Comment: May want to take a look at this.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662891/passing-a-member-function-as-an-argument-in-c

Comment: First gets called one time and second gets called independently later

Comment: You can then create a member object holding a pointer to void function which first assigns to, and second calls it.

Comment: @user yup, a function pointer of the right type would seem to be fine here. `std::function` seems like a tonne of overkill in this case, but people love to suggest it even when none of its special type-erasing features are needed

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You might use *std::function* to store the callable and call it later.

```
class X {
    public:
        void set(std::function<void()> f) {
            callable = f;
        }

        void call() const {
            callable();
        }

    private:
        std::function<void()> callable;
};

void f() {
    std::cout << "Meow" << std::endl;
}
```

Then create X instance and set the callable:

```
X x;
x.set(f);
```

Later call the stored callable:

```
x.call();
```

Comment: upvoted, great c++11 answer, I would only mention that the template is part of the <functional> header

Comment: @user I omit necessary headers as it is usually done in books and presentations to save space...

Comment: Stack Overflow is not space limited in the same way books and presentations are and including preprocessor directives such as `#include` is encouraged.