# Passing a function pointer to a member function in C++.Getting error

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

Hi it is my first experience with passing function pointer in C++.
So here is my code:-

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Two simple functions
class student
{
public:
void fun1() { printf("Fun1\n"); }
void fun2() { printf("Fun2\n"); }

// A function that receives a simple function
// as parameter and calls the function
void wrapper(void (*fun)())
{
    fun();
}
};

int main()
{   student s;

    s.wrapper(s.fun1());
    s.wrapper(s.fun2());
    return 0;
}
```

Initially in wrapper function i passed only fun1 and fun2.I got an error

```
try.cpp:22:15: error: ‘fun1’ was not declared in this scope
     s.wrapper(fun1);
               ^~~~
try.cpp:23:15: error: ‘fun2’ was not declared in this scope
     s.wrapper(fun2);
```

Later I tried to pass s.fun1() and s.fun2() as argument but again got error

```
try.cpp:23:23: error: invalid use of void expression
     s.wrapper(s.fun1());
                       ^
try.cpp:24:23: error: invalid use of void expression
     s.wrapper(s.fun2());
```

Please help I don't know what to do :(

Comment: There's a difference between plain and class member function pointers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing a member function as an argument in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662891/passing-a-member-function-as-an-argument-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's deal with the two issues in the post.

1. You are calling `fun1` and `fun2`. Since their return type is `void`, you can't pass their result as something's value. In particular as the value of a function pointer. You also can't obtain their address by using the dot member access operator. Which brings us to the following.
2. Member functions are not like regular functions. You cannot just take their address. Their treatment is special, because member functions can only be called *on an object*. So there's a special syntax for them, which involves the class they belong to.

Here's how you *would* do something like what you are after:

```
class student
{
public:
    void fun1() { printf("Fun1\n"); }
    void fun2() { printf("Fun2\n"); }

    // A function that receives a member function
    // as parameter and calls the function
    void wrapper(void (student::*fun)())
    {
        (this->*fun)();
    }
};

int main()
{   student s;

    s.wrapper(&student::fun1);
    s.wrapper(&student::fun2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Teller what if fun1 return some int, then how should i write wrapper? I am storing the return of fun1 say in some variable x in main.

Comment: @codie - Then you modify the code to have some return statements, as you would with regular function pointers.