# How to pass a changing member function through another function?

Tags: c++, function-pointers, non-static, pass-by-pointer

I'm trying to pass a function (f1) through another function (f2), while not having to specify f1.

**Example Code**

```
Class C {
    private: std::deque<T*> queue;
    public: edit_queue(std::function<void(T*)> f1, void* input);
};

C::edit_queue(...){
    queue.f1(input);
}
```

However this doesn't compile with error:

```
no member named 'f1' in 'std::__1::deque<T *, std::__1::allocator<T *> >
```

I would like to be able to do both:

```
edit_queue(push_back, T* input);     (1)
```

and

```
edit_queue(push_front, T* input);    (2)
```

I've tried passing a function pointer as well:

```
public: edit_queue(void (*f1)(T*), T* input);
c::edit_queue(...){queue.f1(input);};
```

and

```
private: std::deque<T*>* queue;
...
```

but got the same result.

In addition, is it also possible to not have to specify the inputs of f1 as well? For instance, (1) and (2) would work as well as:

```
edit_queue(pop_back);
```

Comment: "while not having to specify f1." do you mean without fixing the **type** of `f1` ? Passing `f1` to some method without specifying `f1` is a little weird. Moreoever what is `T`?

Comment: Without specifying f1; so f1 can be any member function of deque. T is the type that is being stored in the queue.

Comment: Please read about [mcve]. It is rather hard to make sense of this fragments

Comment: you cannot pass a parameter to a function without "specifiying" what the parameter is

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I pass a member function where a free function is expected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662891/how-can-i-pass-a-member-function-where-a-free-function-is-expected) if I understand correctly what you're looking to do.

Comment: Looks to me like you want to use a lambda.  Then you call `edit_queue` like `edit_queue([](auto& q) { q.push_front(some_value); });` or `edit_queue([](auto& q, auto&& val) { q.push_front(val); }, some_value);`

Comment: Is it possible then to specify the input and outputs of the function and pass that function through? E.g. pass any function of type std::function<void(T*)> through?

Comment: Not if the function is going to be a member function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`f1` isn't a method of `queue` so your code won't compile. You can have different handling of `edit_queue` by passing a lambda instead and calling it:

```
template <typename Container, typename T>
void edit_queue(std::function<void(Container&, const T&)> func, const T& data)
{
  func(queue, data);
}
```

Then call it with a lambda that calls `push_back` or `push_front`.