# std::bind not binding to a library `typedef` ed function

Tags: c++, class, c++17, pointer-to-member, stdbind

I am trying to use `std::bind` with a library that `typedef`s function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

typedef void (*GDBusReturnFunction) (void* user_data);

class Test
{
   void reply(void* user_data)
   {
      std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
      return;
   }

   void test_reply()
   {
      auto reply_func = std::bind(&Test::reply, this, std::placeholders::_1);
      call(reply_func);
   }

   void call(GDBusReturnFunction func)
   {}
};

int main()
{
   Test();
}
```

This is the compile error I am getting

```
prog.cc:19:11: error: cannot convert 'std::_Bind<void (Test::*(Test*, std::_Placeholder<1>))(void*)>' to 'GDBusReturnFunction' {aka 'void (*)(void*)'}
   19 |      call(reply_func);
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~
      |           |
      |           std::_Bind<void (Test::*(Test*, std::_Placeholder<1>))(void*)>
prog.cc:22:33: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'void Test::call(GDBusReturnFunction)'
   22 |   void call(GDBusReturnFunction func)
      |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
```

When I switch the method to `static` and do not use `std::bind` things work as expected.

---

I also tried this

```
     call(&reply_func);
```

but that returns the same error

What am I missing?

Comment: Why are you expecting this to work? `call` expects a function pointer, and you are passing a function object created by `std::bind`. They are unrelated types.

Comment: The function pointer would have nowhere to store the bound arguments. It's a fixed size.

Comment: Not an expert of the matter so it may not be a duplicate, but must be closely related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662891/how-can-i-pass-a-member-function-where-a-free-function-is-expected

Comment: Is `call` supposed to represent a function from the library? If so, then it should have `void *user_data` as a parameter too. Otherwise it can't call `func` because it doesn't know what argument to pass it. Exactly what are you doing? The crux of the whole issue is that a function pointer is *not enough* to represent a function. In C++ we use things like templates+functors/`std::function` instead. In C, a function is conventionally represented by a function pointer plus "some stuff", where "some stuff" is behind a `void*`. Asking for just the function pointer is usually wrong.

Comment: `call` is supposed to represent a function from a library unfortunately. Which does have the `void *` as a parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) returns a *unspecified* type (i.e. a function object of unspecified type),

```
template< class F, class... Args >
/*unspecified*/ bind( F&& f, Args&&... args );
//^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

which can not be copied to a function pointer type.

You need to use

- either [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) or
- a templated `call` function.

Nevertheless, the `std::bind` can be replaced with a [lambda function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)

```
[this](auto user_data) { this->reply(user_data); }
```

A sample solution using templated `Test::call` function, might look like. [See a demo](https://godbolt.org/z/exdKKn)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Test
{
public:
   // optionally you could make it also template function!
   // e.g.
   // template<typename Type>
   // void reply(Type* user_data)
   void reply(void* user_data)
   {
      std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
   }

   void test_reply()
   {
      call([this](auto user_data) { this->reply(user_data); });
   }

   template<typename Callable>
   void call(Callable func) const
   {
      int userData = 1; // some user data
      func(&userData);
   }
};
```

Comment: `GDBusReturnFunction` comes from a library. I don't think OP can just use a different type.

Comment: `GDBusReturnFunction` and `call`  both do come from a library so I cannot change them .. I am going to try a `std::function` approach. I think I understand why std::bind is different from std::function