# C++ function pointer to non static member function

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I have 2 classes: `MeshInput` and `VoxelGrid`. `VoxelGrid` has the member `sdf` which is a function pointer. Now I want to assign a non static function of another class to `sdf`. I can't change the signature of either because `sdf` also sometimes points to a function outside of `MeshInput`. How do I do that?

Code below:

```cpp
class VoxelGrid {
 private:
  double (*sdf)(tg::pos3 const&);
}

class MeshInput {
 public:
  double sdfFromMesh(tg::pos3 const& point);
}
```

From my understanding the Issue is that when calling the function with the function pointer there is no implicit `this*` pointer like when calling it from an object (`A.sdfFromMesh()`). But I don't know how to work around that.

Comment: You cannot do this. Non static member function doesn't have `double (tg::pos3 const&)` signature, its first argument is a pointer to the object. Can you change your raw pointer to `std::function<double(tg::pos3 const&)>` ?

Comment: theres no way to work around. If you want to call a non static member function you need an object. You could bind the object together with the member function pointer though

Comment: Why not just make it `virtual`?

Comment: [How can I pass a member function where a free function is expected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662891/how-can-i-pass-a-member-function-where-a-free-function-is-expected)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::function` cooperate with `std::bind`.

`std::bind` can specific target function to be kept and where it belong. For example:

```
struct Foo
{
    double get(tg::pos3 const&) { return 0; }
};
```

Then you can bind `get` to your variable like this:

```
std::function<double ( tg::pos3 const& )> sdf = std::bind(&Foo::get, &YourFooObj, std::placeholders::_1)
```

see  [std::bind](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) and [std::function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) for more detail.