# "a pointer to a bound function may only be used to call the function" Error when trying to pass a class method

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a `Windows` class as follows:

```
struct PlatformState
{
    HINSTANCE hInstance;
    HWND WindowHandle;
};

class Win32Platform
{
public:
    Win32Platform(const char* app_name, uint32 startX, uint32 startY, uint32 width, uint32 height);
    ~Win32Platform();
private:
    PlatformState* PlatState;
    const char* AppName;
    uint32 StartPosX;
    uint32 StartPosY;
    uint32 Width;
    uint32 Height;
    LRESULT CALLBACK Win32ProcessMessage(HWND window_handle, uint32 msg, WPARAM w_param, LPARAM l_param);    
};
```

When I am trying to create a constructor like this:

```
Win32Platform::Win32Platform(const char* app_name, uint32 startX, uint32 startY
    , uint32 width, uint32 height)

    : AppName(app_name), StartPosX(startX), StartPosY(startY), Width(width), Height(height)
{
    PlatState = nullptr;
    PlatState = (PlatformState *)malloc(sizeof(PlatformState));
    
    PlatState->hInstance = GetModuleHandleA(0);

    //Setup and Register Window Class
    HICON icon = LoadIcon(PlatState->hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);
    WNDCLASSA WinClass;
    WinClass.style = CS_DBLCLKS;
    WinClass.lpfnWndProc = this->Win32ProcessMessage;    
}
```

The driver code is basically:

```
Win32Platform window{"New", 100, 200, 1280, 720};
```

The get the error message

> a pointer to a bound function may only be used to call the function

I need the function `Win32ProcessMessage` as a member function because I need it to access certain class instance variables. I tried it with and without `this`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: `this->Win32ProcessMessage` - you cannot create a pointer to a function like this. `WinClass.lpfnWndProc` requires either a non-member or a `static` member function

Comment: [How can I pass a member function where a free function is expected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662891/how-can-i-pass-a-member-function-where-a-free-function-is-expected)

Comment: I would accept the only provided answer. It looks correct and informative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a *non-static* class method as a Win32 `WndProc` callback, as the method has a hidden `this` parameter which the API can't pass anything into.

To remove the `this` parameter, you need to instead use a *static* class method, or a standalone function.

Then, you can use the `lpParam` parameter of `CreateWindow/Ex()` to pass your object's `this` pointer into your callback. You can handle the `WM_(NC)CREATE` message to receive the pointer, and then store it into the created `HWND` via `SetWindowLongPtr()` or `SetProp()`. In subsequent messages, you can then retrieve the pointer from the `HWND` to access the object as needed.

For example:

```
class Win32Platform
{
    ...
protected:
    ...
    LRESULT ProcessMessage(uint32 msg, WPARAM w_param, LPARAM l_param);    
    ...
private:
    ...
    static LRESULT CALLBACK Win32ProcessMessage(HWND window_handle, uint32 msg, WPARAM w_param, LPARAM l_param);    
    ...
};
```

```
WinClass.lpfnWndProc = &Win32Platform::Win32ProcessMessage;    
...
CreateWindowEx(..., WinClass.lpszClassName, ..., this);
```

```
static LRESULT CALLBACK Win32Platform::Win32ProcessMessage(HWND window_handle, uint32 msg, WPARAM w_param, LPARAM l_param)
{
    Win32Platform *plat;
    if (msg == WM_NCCREATE) {
        plat = (Win32Platform*) ((CREATESTRUCT*)l_Param)->lpCreateParams;
        SetWindowLongPtr(window_handle, GWL_USERDATA, plat);
    }
    else {
        plat = (Win32Platform*) GetWindowLongPtr(window_handle, GWL_USERDATA);
    }

    if (plat)
        return plat->ProcessMessage(msg, w_param, l_Param);

    return DefWindowProc(window_handle, msg, w_param, l_param);
}

LRESULT Win32Platform::ProcessMessage(uint32 msg, WPARAM w_param, LPARAM l_param)
{
    ...
}
```