# C++ passing member function as argument of another member function

Tags: c++, class

I have problem using Borland C++ compiler in Eclipse, I want to pass address of one member function to constructor of another class which is friend of first class

```
PCB::PCB(Thread *t, long stack, int time, void (*method)())
```

I'm using method to find `FP_SEG` and `FP_OFF`, but it's giving me errors when I write

```
Thread::Thread (StackSize stackSize, Time timeSlice){
    myPCB = new PCB(this, stackSize, timeSlice, run);
}
```

This is error I'm getting all the time:

> Could not find a match for 'PCB::PCB(Thread * const,unsigned long,unsigned int,void)' in function Thread::Thread(unsigned long,unsigned int)

Comment: `void (*method)()` isn't a member function pointer.

Comment: But when I add (Thread::*method) FP_OFF(method) doesn't work anymore

Comment: I suggest reading this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/7218633/5404527

Answer (score 4):

Although member function invocation looks like a regular function invocation, the two are not the same, because there is compiler trickery involved in passing the `this` pointer to the function being called. When you call a member-function from another member function, C++ fills in the `this` pointer for you. That is why member functions are incompatible with regular functions, only static functions are.

If you need to pass a function to an API that you did not write, you need to pass a regular function. Otherwise, consider changing the code to take `std::function` instead, because it is compatible with member functions.

Sometimes third-party C-style APIs support passing an extra parameter for the "context" of the call. If your API supports a `void*` as well, you could write a regular function that casts a void pointer coming back to an instance of your class, and call a member function on that instance.