# C++ Member function as a global function's parameter?

Tags: c++, function-pointers

Is there a way to pass member function as a parameter to a global function ?
I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463112/pointer-to-a-c-class-member-function-as-a-global-functions-parameter) but it doesn't really solve my problem.

Lets say that I have following  global functions:

```
double Function(double (*fEval)(double F1, double F2),double min, double max,int numArgs,...);

bool Function2(double (*fEval1)(double F1, double F2),double (*fEval2)(double F1, double F2),double xmin, double xmax, double ymin, double ymax,double &ax, double &ay,int numArgs,...);
```

and one of my member functions calls Function2 as

```
Function2(&F1, &F2, 0, m_m1, 0, m_m2, &m_n1, &m_n2,0);
```

Where F1 and F2 are member functions and Function2 calls somewhere Function1 but at the moment my problem is with Function2 and how to declare it correctly.

Okay now I've managed to change my function declaration to

```
bool Function2(double (CLASS::*)(double F1, double F2),double (CLASS::*)(double F1, double F2),double xmin, double xmax, double ymin, double ymax,double *ax, double *ay,int numArgs,...)
```

And I have probably only one problem which occurs when I'm trying to call the functions fEval1 and fEval2 which have been replaced with  CLASS::* so how I can call the first and second member functions within this function ?

Comment: http://www.newty.de/fpt/callback.html#member

Comment: You need to pass both an object `obj` of type CLASS as well as a pointer to a member function `func` inside of CLASS.  Then you can call the function on the object by doing `obj.*func()`.

Comment: But if I create my object somewhere in main function and these functions will be called within other functions, how I can call that object in this function call if it hasn't been declared :O

Answer (score 4):

Member function pointers are different to ordinary function pointers - you need to specify their class as part of the type.   Also, when calling them, you need to specify an object for which the member function is called.

Your error message shows that the type of member-function which you're passing is in fact `double (CLASS::*)(double, double)`  - this isn't compatible with the ordinary function pointer type in the signature

Have a look at the C++ FAQ here for a bit more information on how to use member function pointers:

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html

Answer (score 4):

It's *sort of* possible to do this, but it's open to a lot of question whether it's what you really want to do.

There is such a thing as a pointer to a member function, *but* it acts as basically an offset within a struct, so to use it you need to supply both the pointer to the member function, *and* an object on which to invoke that member function. Given what you're doing, it looks unlikely (at least to me) that you really want this.

My immediate reaction would be to write your `Function1` and `Function2` as templates, and pass functors instead of pointers to functions. Instead of specifying a normal member function, each will do like other functors, and overload `operator()` to do the work.

Edit: I'd also avoid using variadic functions if you can -- they throw away type information, which is one of the definite no-nos in C++. Especially with new C++ compilers that support C++11, it's almost always pretty easy to avoid it (you can pass an initializer list that creates an object instead).

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into that and keep that in my mind. In this case I'll have to use arglist because in some cases I need to change the boundaries within the function. I think this is better way than write 3 or 4 overloaded functions with different amount of aguments.

Comment: @Mare: The idea was to pass something like an `std:vector`. It's generally pretty easy to pass a different size of vector when/if needed.

Comment: Oh that's really brilliant! I don't know why I haven't never thought something like that.